# Generate legend with matplotlib based on the values in column

Tags: matplotlib, legend

Assume we have a dataframe of 4 individuals' scores in 2 different tests and the 3rd column tells us if they passed or failed overall

df:

```
[10,20,failed
 10,40,passed
 20,40,passed
 30,10,failed]
```

I would like to generate a scatter plot with the scores of the 1st column on the x axis, the scores of the 2nd test on the y axis, and indicate with color (or marker) if they passed or failed. I have achieved this with:

```
plt.scatter(x=df[column1], y=df[column2], c=df[column3])
```

The question is, how can I have a legend based on the color (or marker) and column3?

```
[red: failed
 blue: passed]
```

Comment: Thank you Sheldore for pointing out the possible duplication. Looking at bexi's solution though I feel it is worth keeping this question open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion: Plot the failed an passed separately to get their handles, which can then be used for the legend.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

passed = ax1.scatter(x=df.loc[df[column3].eq('passed'), column1], y=df.loc[df[column3].eq('passed'), column2], c='green')
failed = ax1.scatter(x=df.loc[df[column3].eq('failed'), column1], y=df.loc[df[column3].eq('failed'), column2], c='red')

ax1.legend(handles=[passed, failed], labels=['Passed', 'Failed'])
```

Comment: thank you bexi for the elegant solution!